# Python overwrite to file in wrong order

Tags: python, linux, unit-testing

When I run my program with ./program.py >temp.out

I get all the unit test output first then the prints I am putting in in the python. Is there anyway I can get this to appear in this file the way it does on screen?

```
Test Results Suite "curl"
                               Name:     Checks  Failures   Time (s)
                        couch check:          -         -   Disabled
                   couch check fail:          -         -   Disabled
                database check fail:          -         -   Disabled
                    create database:          -         -   Disabled
                     database check:          -         -   Disabled
                  upload design doc:          -         -   Disabled
                     remove_witness:          -         -   Disabled
====================================================================
                              Total:          0         0

Passed
+=================================================================+
| Running: hba_test                                               |
| Skipping:abort/"Basic Sanity" delayedabort/"Abort Control List" |
+=================================================================+
+====================+
| Skipping: sdt_test |
+====================+
+======================+
| Skipping: dtd_tester |
+======================+
+===============+
| Running: pssm |
+===============+
+==============+
| Running: psm |
+==============+
```

This is the code which executes each unit test and prints seperate headers around them

```
#calculate lengths to make sure header is correct length
        l1 = len(x)
        l2 = len(y)
        #if entire test suite is to be disabled
        if disable:
            headerBreak ="+" + "="*(l1+12) + "+"
            print headerBreak
            print "| Skipping: %s |" % x
        #if the test suite will be executed
        else:
            headerBreak =  "+" + "="*(max(l1,l2)+11) + "+"
            print headerBreak
            print "| Running: %s" % x, ' '*(l2-l1)+ '|'
            #if some suites are disabled but some are still running
            if 'disable=' in test:
               print "| Skipping:%s |" % y 
        print headerBreak
        #bitshift right to obtain correct return value, execution of each test.
        returnValue = os.system(path) >> 8
        #running total of failures in the program.
        failures += returnValue
```

Last bit of code to run the method

```
#execute tests failures = execTests(path, testList)
#exit program with returncode as number of failures sys.exit(failures)
```

It should appear like this:

```
+==============+
| Running: ssm |
+==============+

Test Results Suite "Secondary Set Manager Tests"
                               Name:     Checks  Failures   Time (s)
              SSM_1 validate checks:         30         0      0.002
                 SSM_2 group create:          6         0      0.001
           SSM_3 rcvd invalid group:          3         0      0.001
            SSM_4 rcvd invalid data:          9         0      0.001
               SSM_5 aborted subset:          7         0      0.000
          SSM_6 pri node down abort:         14         0      0.000
        SSM_7 excess ios in subsets:          6         0      0.000
              SSM_8 all ss received:         11         0      0.000
                  SSM_9 applying ss:         12         0      0.000
               SSM_10 applying ss 2:         18         0      0.000
            SSM_11 subsets complete:         32         0      0.001
     SSM_12 subsets complete errors:         19         0      0.000
           SSM_13 apply waiting set:         40         0      0.000
                 SSM_14 extend test:         14         0      0.000
               SSM_15 group destroy:          6         0      0.000
                 SSM_16 null params:          2         0      0.001
                  SSM_17 stop group:         26         0      0.001
                SSM_18 dupe receive:          6         0      0.000
           SSM_19 apply waiting set:         36         0      0.001
====================================================================
                              Total:        297         0

Test Results Suite "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"
                               Name:     Checks  Failures   Time (s)
             SSSM_1 Validate Checks:         14         0      0.001
                SSSM_2 Steady State:         92        42      0.001
              SSSM_3 Multi Sequence:        417       227      0.003
                  SSSM_4 Test Abort:         69         6      0.001
      SSSM_5 Test Inconsistent Mreq:         10         0      0.001
                 SSSM_6 Test extend:         37         1      0.001
          SSSM_7 Test unexpected IO:         11         0      0.001
            SSSM_8 test null params:          5         0      0.000
                  SSSM_9 exceptions:          0         1      0.001
            SSSM_10 done_incomplete:         20         0      0.001
                  SSSM_11 failed io:         92        42      0.001
====================================================================
                              Total:        767       319
Failed Cases [ssm]:
   Secondary Subset Manager Tests/"SSSM_2 Steady State"
   Secondary Subset Manager Tests/"SSSM_3 Multi Sequence"
   Secondary Subset Manager Tests/"SSSM_4 Test Abort"
   Secondary Subset Manager Tests/"SSSM_6 Test extend"
   Secondary Subset Manager Tests/"SSSM_9 exceptions"
   Secondary Subset Manager Tests/"SSSM_11 failed io"


Overall Failures: 319
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, the text in the file is in a different order than when printed on the console? There's no missing lines at all?

Comment: @goncalopp: it is redirected..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I got that, I was just wondering if something was going to `stderr`, thus missing on the file

Comment: I believe everything is present in the file, it's just in the wrong order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you redirect output from the terminal to a file, the buffering mode changes from line buffered to using a fixed-size buffer instead. This means that newlines no longer trigger a flush.

Your `print` outputs are therefore being buffered, but the tests you are running with `os.system()` have *their* buffers flushed when the process completes.

The solution is to explicitly flush after your `print` statements, just before you run `os.system()`:

```
import sys

# ....
print headerBreak
sys.stdout.flush()
returnValue = os.system(path) >> 8
```

Comment: do I need to do this after every single statement?

Comment: Once per test should be enough.